# Why using channel in this function?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I was studying [a blog](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/12/scheduling-in-go-part3.html) about the timing of using go-routines, and I saw the example pasted below, from line 61 to line 65. But I don't get the purpose of using channel here.

It seems that he is iterating the channels to retrieve the msg inside go-routine.
But why not directly using string array?

```golang
58 func findConcurrent(goroutines int, topic string, docs []string) int {
59     var found int64
60
61     ch := make(chan string, len(docs))
62     for _, doc := range docs {
63         ch <- doc
64     }
65     close(ch)
66
67     var wg sync.WaitGroup
68     wg.Add(goroutines)
69
70     for g := 0; g < goroutines; g++ {
71         go func() {
72             var lFound int64
73             for doc := range ch {
74                 items, err := read(doc)
75                 if err != nil {
76                     continue
77                 }
78                 for _, item := range items {
79                     if strings.Contains(item.Description, topic) {
80                         lFound++
81                     }
82                 }
83             }
84             atomic.AddInt64(&found, lFound)
85             wg.Done()
86         }()
87     }
88
89     wg.Wait()
90
91     return int(found)
92 }
```

Comment: I don't know why the author chose to use a channel there. I agree that using the slice directly would probably make sense. Maybe it's just an excuse to demonstrate a channel. Without a link to the original blog post, or asking the author directly, it's only possible to guess.

Comment: Using a string slice will definitely cause race condition specially when used inside go routines. 

Its better to use channels when working with go routines to read/write range of values. 

PS : U can use slices as well but it will require use of mutexes, in go channels are better in this use case

Comment: @RaviChandak are you certain? The code is just reading from the `docs` slice, is that really gonna cause a race condition?

Comment: @mkopriva on looking again in this case I agree with you but .. 
if the docs slice itself can be probably updated or passed around from the caller function.

Comment: If you want to explain in simple terms how goroutines and channels work together you need to use goroutines and channels and not slices and for loops. Of course you could just keep the docs slice and have the goroutines pick from that slice. *But* this picking would need syncronisation. The provided solution is a very simple one if you have N goroutines work on M documents with N!=M.

Comment: @Flimzy link attached

Comment: channel is just a medium of passing data from one goroutine to another, as far as I see there is no goroutine other than `func()` , the use of channel here is just not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is providing an example of a way of distributing work (finding strings within documents) amongst multiple goRoutines. Basically the code is starting `goroutines` and feeding them documents to search via a channel.

> But why not directly using string array?

It would be possible to use a string array and a variable (lets call it `count`) to track what item in the array you were up to. You would have some code like (a little long winded to demonstrate a point):

```
for {
   if count > len(docarray) {
      break;
   }
   doc := docarray[count]
   count++
   // Process the document
}
```

However you would hit syncronisation issues. For example what happens if two go routines (running on different processor cores) get to `if count > len(docarray)` at the same time? Without something to prevent this they might both end up processing the same item in the slice (and potentially skipping the next element because they both run `count++`).

Syncronization of processes is complex and issues can be very hard to debug. Using channels hides a lot of this complexity from you and makes it more likely that your code will work as expected (it does not solve all issues; note the use of `atomic.AddInt64(&found, lFound)` in the example code to prevent another potential issue that would result from multiple go routines writing to a variable at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

The author seems to just be using a contrived example to illustrate how channels work. Perhaps it would be desirable for him to come up with a more realistic example. But he does say:

> *Note: There are several ways and options you can take when writing a concurrent version of add. Don’t get hung up on my particular implementation at this time. If you have a more readable version that performs the same or better I would love for you to share it.*

So it seems clear he wasn't trying to write the best code for the job, just something to illustrate his point.

Comment: still the point of use of channel is confusing from author POV.

Answer (score 0):

he is using buffered channel so i dont think channel is doing any special work here, any normal string slice will also do the same.